# Webpack - UglifyJs RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, uglifyjs

I got a legacy vue.js project with webpack: 4.44.1

When I launching build command
`webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress`
It's started to the building, and throw an error on 92%

```
ERROR in assets/js/common.js from UglifyJs RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

How can I fix that error? I saw that guys launch node build with max-callstack parameter, but I don't know is there some similar params on webpack?

My package:

```
    {
  "name": "webpack-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Webpack-starter project",
  "main": " ",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^8.6.5",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.6",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "vue-loader": "15.2.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanem/svg-injector": "^8.0.27",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "body-scroll-lock": "^2.6.4",
    "countup.js": "^2.0.4",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "svg-injector": "^1.1.3",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-countup-v2": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-dragscroll": "^1.10.0",
    "vue-masked-input": "^0.5.2",
    "vue-perfect-scrollbar": "^0.2.0",
    "vue-resize": "^0.4.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-slick": "^1.1.15",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1"
  }
}
```

and production webpack config (`webpack.config.prod.js`)

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
let Config = require("./webpack.config.js");

Config.devtool = "cheap-source-map";

Config.mode = 'production';

Config.optimization = {
    minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
};

Config.plugins = (Config.plugins || []).concat([
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, "./assets/"),
            to: path.resolve(__dirname, "../Bs.WebApp/wwwroot/assets/")
        }
    ])
]);

module.exports = Config;
```

Answer (score 1):

Removed `new UglifyJsPlugin(),` used `afterConfig.optimization.minimize`

So that part of the config looks like:

```
Config.optimization = {
    minimizer: [
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
};

Config.optimization.minimize;
```

Comment: I removed it as well! No need for it!